# query multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a function set up to show 'Similar Products', i.e. showing products that share the same `products-category` taxonomy term. This works great but I want to narrow the function even further and make it more specific. Thus I want it to look at 2 taxonomies (`product-category` and `space`) to find similar products. The current markup as follows:

```
    <?php  
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'products-category' );
    if($terms){
      // post has course_type terms attached
      $course_terms = array();
      foreach ($terms as $term){
       $course_terms[] = $term->slug;
      }

     $original_query = $wp_query;
     $wp_query = null;
     $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => '4',
            'post_type' => 'regularproducts',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'products-category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $course_terms, //the taxonomy terms I'd like to dynamically query
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        )
    );

    if ( have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> //etc...
```

So it currently only looks at the `products-category` taxonomy for similar products (posts), but I want it to look at BOTH `product-category` and `space` to display more specific similar products, if possible. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add another array in `'tax_query' => array(` this should solve your problem.

Comment: @SLH yes but what about `$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'products-category' );` as this is only using the `product-category` taxonomy term?

Comment: Then create other variable $space_terms and get the terms by post ID for your second taxonomy. `array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'space',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $space_terms,
                ),`

Comment: @SLH ok, unless its something I'm doing wrong...would you possibly be able to put the full code in an answer so I can test?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, get all term slugs from the custom taxonomy `space` by current post ID.

```
$space_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'space' );
if( $space_terms ) {
  $space_terms = array();
  foreach( $space_terms as $term ) {
   $space_terms[] = $term->slug;
  }
}
```

You should specify the logical relationship between each inner taxonomy array when there is more than one.

The `relation` key in the array describes the relationship. Possible values are `OR` and `AND`.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'products-category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $course_terms,
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'space',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $space_terms,
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simply get all terms first:** Here i used property custom post type for example

```
$property_statu_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_status', array(  'fields' => 'ids' ));
$property_type_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_type', array(  'fields' => 'ids' ));
$property_city_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_city', array(  'fields' => 'ids' ));
$property_state_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_state', array(  'fields' => 'ids' ));
$property_feature_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'property_feature', array(  'fields' => 'ids' ));
```

Use `relation` [[OR] or [AND]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) to get your desired posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(

    'post_type'             => 'property',
    'posts_per_page'        => 3,
    'orderby'               => 'rand',
    'post__not_in'          => array( $post->ID ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_status',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $property_statu_terms,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_type',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $property_type_terms,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_city',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $property_city_terms,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_state',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $property_state_terms,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'property_feature',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $property_feature_terms,
        ),
    ),

));
```