# Filter custom posts by multiple taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, multi-taxonomy-query

Im working with custom post types - named 'Products'

I have multiple taxonomies registered - 'Category' and 'Dosage'

And I'm trying to setup pages that only display custom post types 'products' IF taxonomy Category='injectors' AND Dosage='1ml, 2ml, 5ml'

I hope that makes sense - manage to get custom post archives working fine for a single taxonomy, but not sure about filtering by multiple.

Cheers,

This is the code i'm trying to get work but it doesn't

```
<?php 
$myquery['tax_query'] = array( 
   'relation' => 'OR', 
    array( 
         'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
         'terms' => array('shrouded'),
         'field' => 'slug', 
    ), 
    array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'dosages',
        'terms' => array( '1ml' ),
        'field' => 'slug', 
   ),
);
query_posts($myquery); ?>
```

Comment: Seems like this has been already discussed and solved here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167944/query-multiple-taxonomies

Comment: Also in your question you mention "AND" but in query you are using "OR".

Answer (score 1):

This should not be using `query_posts`, for that matter nothing should ever be using `query_posts` as there are better ways to modify the main query before execution. See [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

That said, based on the use case this should be handled with an additional custom query, not a modification to the main query.

Also the question cites the need for an AND relationship between the 2 taxonomies, but then uses OR in the code example.

**Solution**:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'products',
   'posts_per_page' => -1, //<-- Get all
   'tax_query' = array( 
      'relation' => 'AND', 
      array( 
         'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
         'terms' => array('injectors'),
         'field' => 'slug', 
      ), 
      array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'dosages',
        'terms' => array( '1ml','2ml','5ml' ),
        'field' => 'slug'
      )
   )
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
if($products->have_posts()) : while($products->have_posts()) : the_post() ;
   // Output desired markup inside custom query loop here.
endwhile; endif; `
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this examples help you figure things out:

- [List all posts in custom post type by taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/list-all-posts-in-custom-post-type-by-taxonomy)
- https://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/using-wordpress-to-query-multiple-taxonomies

Comment: Thanks for the link, it sounds promising but can't seem to get it to work.  Can you spot anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

<?php 
$myquery['tax_query'] = array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
 array(
  'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
  'terms' => array('shrouded'),
  'field' => 'slug',
 ),
 array(
  'taxonomy' => 'dosages',
  'terms' => array('1ml'),
  'field' => 'slug',
 ),

);
query_posts($myquery);
 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `query_posts`, you're overriding the whole archive query, so you have to specify your custom post type in your query parameters, like so:

```
$myquery['post_type'] = 'products';
```

However, the better solution would be to avoid `query_posts` altogether, so the main query doesn't get broken, and use one of the other approaches as described in the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).